# Example code PHP / C# AES encryption - random IV

Tags: c#, php, aes

I found an implementation for AES encryption/decryption that's supposed to work in PHP and C#:
https://odan.github.io/2017/08/10/aes-256-encryption-and-decryption-in-php-and-csharp.html

However, in this example, the IV is always 0, which is not good.
So, as the author suggests, I use the openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() function:

```
  $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);
  $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
```

However, the problem now is, that I have to store the IV somewhere so that the C# app can use it for decryption. My idea was to base64_encode it and prepend it to the encrypted message with ":" separating both, so that I can simply split the string, then base64 decode it in C# and can use the IV. However, this does not work. This is the code:

```
public string DecryptString(string cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
{
    // Instantiate a new Aes object to perform string symmetric encryption
    Aes encryptor = Aes.Create();

    encryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

    // Set key and IV
    byte[] aesKey = new byte[32];
    Array.Copy(key, 0, aesKey, 0, 32);
    encryptor.Key = aesKey;
    encryptor.IV = iv;

    // Instantiate a new MemoryStream object to contain the encrypted bytes
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    // Instantiate a new encryptor from our Aes object
    ICryptoTransform aesDecryptor = encryptor.CreateDecryptor();

    // Instantiate a new CryptoStream object to process the data and write it to the 
    // memory stream
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aesDecryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    // Will contain decrypted plaintext
    string plainText = String.Empty;

    try {
        // Convert the ciphertext string into a byte array
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

        // Decrypt the input ciphertext string
        cryptoStream.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes . Length);

        // Complete the decryption process
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        // Convert the decrypted data from a MemoryStream to a byte array
        byte[] plainBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

        // Convert the decrypted byte array to string
        plainText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
    } finally {
        // Close both the MemoryStream and the CryptoStream
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();
    }

    // Return the decrypted data as a string
    return plainText;
}
```

And this is how I try to call the function with the IV prepended to the encrypted message:

```
private void btnDecrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string encrypted = txtEncrypted.Text;
            string password = txtPW.Text;
            string[] temp = encrypted.Split(":".ToCharArray());
            string iv_str = temp[0];
            encrypted = temp[1];
            SHA256 mySHA256 = SHA256Managed.Create();
            byte[] key = mySHA256.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password));
            iv_str = Encoding.Default.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(iv_str));
            byte[] iv = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(iv_str);

            txtDecrypted.Text = this.DecryptString(encrypted, key, iv); 
        }
```

Doesn't work. It decrypts something, but that's just gibberish and not the message I encrypted in PHP.
I think it has to do with the IV somehow.

Comment: Encryption you have public keys and private keys.  The private keys should never be sent with the message.  Sending the private key with the data makes it easy for hackers to decrypt the data.  The private key should be sent separately and in a secure fashion so hacker won't get both the encrypted message and the private key.

Comment: As far as I know this is a symmetric encryption. I do not prepend the key, but the IV, which is necessary for the decryption, isn' it?

Comment: Usually the concatenation is done on byte level, first the IV, then the ciphertext and the result is Base64 encoded. A separator isn't necessary, because the size of the IV is known (blocksize of the cipher, i.e. 16 bytes for AES). But your way should also work. A possible error source is the encoding: In `btnDecrypt_Click`, `iv_str` is Base64 decoded, then decoded to a string using the default encoding and finally encoded using the ASCII encoding. The last two steps are wrong. If `iv_str` is Base64 encoded, `byte[] iv = Convert.FromBase64String(iv_str)` is sufficient.

Comment: You never send the key with the data.  It would be similar to give a robber a key to your house.

Comment: @jdweng - As far as I can see, the key isn't sent with the data but derived from a password (although SHA256 isn't a good choice as KDF, PBKDF2 would be better, [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/16357)). If you refer to the IV, the IV is _no secret_ ([here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/17046)) and may be sent unencrypted e.g. typically together with the ciphertext!

Comment: I don't care what other people do that is against good practice.  You should never give a buglar a key to your house.  Never send the encryption key with the data.

Comment: _Never send the encryption key with the data._ True, but since no key is sent here, the statement is pointless in this context.

Answer (score 0):

@Topaco:
Thank you very much... now I see what my mistake was. It works now with generated IV. 
By the way, two more questions on the strength of the encryption:

1. Is it ok to use the following function to generate an IV (GenerateIV() for some reason won't work):

   byte[] iv = new byte[16];
   Random rnd = new Random();
   rnd.NextBytes(iv);
2. I added a randomly generated salt to the password of the user, so that the key is a hash from the user password and a salt. I also prepend the salt, together with the now randomly generated IV, to the message. Then for the decryption process I use the prepended salt and the key the user enters. Works so far. But does it weaken the encryption? No, right?

Thank you very much.

// Edit: Code format doesn't work, don't know why.